# PyDev improperly warns of unused import statement

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I've got the following Python code in a module:

```
import ldap
import ldap.sasl
x = ldap.VERSION3
y = ldap.sasl.gssapi
```

Eclipse (with PyDev) warns me that my first import statement is unused. But it's clearly being used. Python apparently implicitly imports parent packages -- which I find weird, since Python prefers explicit, and I can't find any mention of this in the documentation. But that doesn't mean that I'm not using the first. Even more odd, if I remove the last line, PyDev claims that **both** of the import statements are unused. (I think this last case is clearly a bug in PyDev.)

So my question is, is there a way to turn off the warning for the first line, without turning off warnings for all unused imports? And I'd rather not pollute my code with `@UnusedImport` comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right answer here is to do what PyDev says.

Because `import ldap.sasl` always imports `ldap`, the `import ldap` statement is not necessary, and therefore should be removed.

---

As for PyDev claiming that both are unused if you remove the last line… Well, that's definitely not the best messaging in the world, but it's not really *wrong*. The `import ldap` is unnecessary because you have `import ldap.sasl`. But the `import ldap.sasl` is unnecessary because you never use it. True, if you remove the `import ldap.sasl`, then the `import ldap` stops being unnecessary, but the warnings aren't about what would be true for a different version of your code, right?

---

You're right that the [tutorial section on Packages](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) doesn't explain this at all, and the 2.x reference documentation doesn't really say anything directly about it.

However, the 3.x reference documentation on [the import system](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/import.html#importsystem) specifically describes this behavior, and gives examples (e.g., see the "Regular packages" section), and the 2.x reference does directly refer to the [original package spec](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/packages.html), which says:

> Whenever a submodule of a package is loaded, Python makes sure that the package itself is loaded first, loading its `__init__.py` file if necessary. The same for packages. Thus, when the statement import Sound.Effects.echo is executed, it first ensures that Sound is loaded; then it ensures that Sound.Effects is loaded; and only then does it ensure that Sound.Effects.echo is loaded (loading it if it hasn't been loaded before).

Also, all existing Python 2.x implementations do things the way the 3.x documentation and the original package spec describe, and it's not likely people will be creating brand-new 2.x implementations in the future, so I think you can rely on this being a guarantee.

---

If you want to know the original rationale, you have to read the `ni` module from Python 1.3. (I don't have a link for it.) If you want to know why it's still that way in 2.7, it's because the first radical cleanup in Python didn't happen until 3.0. If you want to know why it's *still* that way in 3.0, and even in 3.3 (after `import` was improved and further cleaned up), you'll have to read the discussions around [PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/), `importlib`, etc. on [python-ideas](http://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-ideas) and [python-dev](http://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-dev). When there's a consensus *not* to change something (or when there's so little discussion that nobody even finds it necessary to call for a consensus), you don't get a PEP or any other "paper trail" outside the mailing lists. If I remember correctly, it did come up in passing while discussing the relative-vs.-absolute import ideas that became PEP 328, but nobody thought it was a problem that needed to be fixed.